# Oracle PHP PDO exception: could not find driver

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm trying to hack together a script to connect to a remote oracle database and execute a simple query

Through extensive searches I found the following script:

```
<?

$tns = "
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = bogus.com.au)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = myDB )
        )
    )
";


$pdo_string = 'oci:dbname='.$tns;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($pdo_string, 'test', 'fake');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to obtain database handle: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM someTable";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "<h4>$query</h4>";
    echo "<pre>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

However I'm getting the error `could not find driver`. So I did:

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '<br>';
```

Which returned:

```
mysql
odbc
sqlite
```

That tells me that I do have the driver installed, yes?

What am I doing wrong? (Admittedly I have little to no knowledge of PHP with Oracle databases so maybe I'm missing the blatantly obvious..)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install Oracle adapter in PDO:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Comment: Thanks. I had a read through and it says `Use --with-pdo-oci[=DIR] to install the PDO Oracle OCI extension` I wouldn't have a clue on how to do that. Would you say I'm trying to bite off more than I can chew at this point? Is there a more straight forward way of doing this? connecting to a MySQL DB was not so convoluted..

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to enable the PDO_OCI extension.

Go to `php.ini` and find the line `extension=php_pdo_oci.dll` and remove the comma `;` from its start then restart your apache service.